# Почему чаще говорят про звук "длинный", чем "долгий". Или это не так?

Tags: семантика, лексикология

И почти не говорят " продолжительный".

Comment: Если лишь говорят, а не пишут, то насколько оценки достоверны?

Comment: А почему чаще говорят длинный, а не высокий. Какое-то привилегированное слово. Так это или не так, мы должны видеть в вашем вопросе. Есть три инструмента для сбора статистики, гугл, гугл-книги и нацкорпус. Проверьте по всем. Почему чаще говорят говорят, а не пишут